# Show pages according to url AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I am making a Angular project with Spring MVC.

What I need to do is get the parameter from url and show the pages accordingly.

For example :

```
cms.example.com -- > so it will go to the cms signup/login page

login.example.com --->  so it will go to the only login page

somename.example.com --->  so it will go to the login page but with parameter somename
```

Since Angular is a SPA(Single Page Application) I made a controller which fetches the full url and returns

```
cms.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http,  $window) { 
    var y =  window.location.host.split('.');
    var z = y[0];

    if ( z == "cms" )
    {
        $scope.logincms = z;
        //console.log($scope.logincms);
    }
    else if ( z == "login" )
    {
        $scope.logincms = z;
        //console.log($scope.logincms);
    }
    else
    {  //404 or success page  }         
});
```

and used ng-if in html page like if it equals `login` then it will show login html, if it is `cms` then it will show login/signup page. **BUT**

I have seen a website cliniko.com. There they make the same kind of app but I didn't see any ng-if in their html. Just wondering how they do it or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Look at angular router.

Comment: I would have each host entry include a specific JS file that could set the appropriate state / configuration for you. This question is too broad to answer directly without more information about your app or a specific question or problem you're having

Comment: @phil what more info do you need

Answer (score -1):

Use $routeProvider. What you are doing is not correct.

$routeProvider does exactly what you are looking for. You can refer it here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: That's not correct at all. `$routeProvider` does **not** route on the host part of the URL